# Curious behaviour of print_function in __future__ module on Python 3

Tags: python, python-import

I observed a strange behaviour of the `__future__` module's `print_function` in Python 3.2.

Take, for example this code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

print('Enter the base path of the images: ', end='')
path = sys.stdin.readline().strip().strip('"')
if len(path) == 0:
    print("No path entered")
else:
    print(root)
print("\n\nPress ENTER to exit")
exit = sys.stdin.readline()
```

When the script is run, it appears the console waits for the user to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> before displaying the first `print` statement.
The output then looks like this:

```
Enter the base path of the images: No path entered


Press ENTER to exit
```

Needless to day, displaying an empty prompt to the user leads to a lot of confusion especially since a lot of people are afraid of the black window with white text (Command Prompt).

When the code is changed to this

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

print('\nEnter the base path of the images: ', end='') #line now starts with \n
path = sys.stdin.readline().strip().strip('"')
if len(path) == 0:
    print("No path entered")
else:
    print(path)
print("\n\nPress ENTER to exit")
exit = sys.stdin.readline()
```

Then the output is as expected (assuming we ignore the preceding empty line):

```
Enter the base path of the images: c:\
c:\


Press ENTER to exit
```

When the code is run in python 2.6 however, the first one works as expected (i.e. it displays `Enter the base path of the images:` *before* waiting to receive input).

This leads me to ask:
Why do I need to precede the `print` function with a `\n` in order to get an output displayed in Python 3.2 while I don't need the `\n` when running in Python 2.6?
Could it be that the `print_function` is implemented differently in the two versions?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `sys.stdin.readline()` instead of `input`?  Presumably for python2.x compatability?

Comment: `input` in Python 2 attempts to evaluate anything typed, (not what I want). In Python 3, it just captures the input (what I want). `raw_input` captures the input (what I want) but it only works in Python 2, not 3 so it's inconvenient. Using `sys.stdin.readline()` allows me to use the same function call in both versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are seeing the effects of line buffering. Flush `stdout` first (using `sys.stdout.flush()` for backwards compatibility with Python 2):

```
print('Enter the base path of the images: ', end='')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

The `print()` function in Python 2 is certainly different from the one in Python 3 (where the `from __future__ import print_function` line is effectively meaningless). In Python 3, I/O has been overhauled and `stdout` buffering semantics have changed subtly. In Python 2, the `sys.stdin.readline()` call flushes `stdout` automatically, in Python 3 this is no longer the case.

If you use the `input()` function instead of reading from `stdin` directly, you do not need to flush at all:

```
msg = 'Enter the base path of the images: '
try:
    # python 2
    path = raw_input(msg)
except NameError:
    # python 3
    path = input(msg)
```

Comment: This is the solution I worked out too -- Except I LBYL -- `if sys.version_info < (3,): input = raw_input` ... I'm shadowing the builtin `input` that way -- but I'm not too bent out of shape about that one ;-)

Comment: Python 3 doesn't entirely ignore the future import: it will still bind the name 'print_function' in the current scope to the imported value. There's just no magic meaning assigned to that import in Python 3.

Comment: @Duncan: Did I miss out the word "effectively" again did I? :-P

Comment: Since calling `input` (or `raw_input` in Python 2) flushes the output buffer, I reassigned the `input` function to a common one based on the version of python running like so `if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    input = raw_input`. Now I call a single function to flush and collect input from the user irrespective of the version of python executing the script.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I'd check my python version and substitute the appropriate "input" function:
Now you can just use `input` wherever you want user interaction.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

if sys.version_info < (3,):
    input = raw_input

path = input('Enter the base path of the images> ').strip().strip('"')
if len(path) == 0:
    print("No path entered")
else:
    print(path)

print("\n\nPress ENTER to exit")
exit = input()
```

Comment: And as a side note, with the code posted above, you no longer even need the future import -- Making this code work with **MUCH** older python versions than even 2.6. -- Maybe back as far as python2.0 ...